# JavaEE: Login-config, different forms for different roles

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/webapp/web_xml.html#1045762) seems to suggest that it is not possible to define a form based on the role he'd like to apply for.

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form>
    <form-error-page>/loginerror.xhtml</form>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
```

E.g. navigating to xxx.xx/admin would go to adminlogin.xhtml and navigating to xxx.xx/account would go to login.xhtml.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

PS. Normally you would deploy the adminpanel to a subdomain, though due to specifications this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to accomplish this, and with good reason.
User can belong to several roles, and even though you may configer different security-constraint to /admin/*, /account/*, or /whatever/* the user can grant all these roles, some of them or none.
Anyway, this can't be known in advance.

Comment: Hmm, I think I will redesign my entities a bit to better fit this. Since this is a bit of a best practice ofcourse. Thanks for your explanation.